# Querying with joined table id in JPA without NativeQuery

Tags: java, jpa

My object is

```
@Entity
public class DiscoveryResult {
     .....
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn
      private Company company;
     ....
```

I want to querying like this;

```
@Query(value="SELECT scope from DiscoveryResult where company = :companyId group by scope")
List<String> findDistinctCategories(long companyId);
```

How can I query by id which under company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `DiscoveryResult` and `Company` entities and then compare the `id` column of the `Company` with the `companyId` query parameter.

```
@Query(value="SELECT r.scope from DiscoveryResult r JOIN r.company c where c.id = :companyId group by scope")
List<String> findDistinctCategories(long companyId);
```